# How to show different view page for mobile device in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I want to load views from two different folders.
1. views (for desktop)
2. mobile (for mobile devices)
The view files will be in same name. If run from mobile and the required file is not in mobile folder, the file from view folder will be loaded. The application is divided into different modules with separate views, controllers and route file. I have done the condition in the moduleServiceProvider.php in module folder:

```
<?php namespace App\Modules;
class ModuleServiceProvider extends  \Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider
{
public function boot()
{
    $useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $modules = config("module.modules");
    while (list(,$module) = each($modules)) {
        if(file_exists(__DIR__.'/'.$module.'/routes.php'))
        {
            include __DIR__.'/'.$module.'/routes.php';
        }
        if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',$useragent))
        {
            if(is_dir(__DIR__.'/'.$module.'/mobile'))
            {
                $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/'.$module.'/mobile', $module);
            }
            else
            {
                if(is_dir(__DIR__.'/'.$module.'/Views'))
                {
                    $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/'.$module.'/Views', $module);
                }
            }
        }
        else if(is_dir(__DIR__.'/'.$module.'/Views'))
        {
            $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/'.$module.'/Views', $module);
        }
    }
}
}
```

But right now, if there is three pages in view folder and only one or two pages with the same name in the mobile folder those pages load perfectly in the mobile device. But the third page (which is only in view folder, but not in mobile folder) doesn't load in mobile device. Because the app finds the mobile directory, but fails to find the page. It doesn't load the page from the view folder. It would be great if anyone could help me without doing anything in the controller or route file. Thanks.
Folder Structure:

```
app  
core
config  
.  
.  
.  
modules  
   module1  
      controllers  
         controllerA.php  
         controllerB.php  
         controllerC.php  
      forms
      views
         viewA.blade.php
         viewB.blade.php
         viewC.blade.php
      mobile  
         viewA.blade.php  
         viewC.blade.php  
      route.php  
   module2  
      controllers  
      forms  
      views  
      mobile  
   module3  
   module4  
   moduleServiceProvider.php
facades  
public  
resources  
.  
.  
.
```

Comment: can you provide your view folder structure?

Comment: Also why are you doing this `while (list(,$module) = each($modules))` I thought ONLY one module can be loaded at a given time, why are you looping?

Answer (score 0):

you can use https://matthewdaly.co.uk/blog/2018/04/22/rendering-different-views-for-mobile-and-desktop-clients-in-laravel/.it helps you to detect mobile
and use https://github.com/Torann/device-view, it will help you to dynamically select between views.

Comment: add some description

Comment: the first link helps you to get agent and store it in the session, then helps you to define two helper function for faster access to its result in anywhere at you website.
the second link is my suggestion to use, with that you can easily send your result for your separate views. it means, you will be free to choosing views in each controller, in this way, you just prepare the data and send it to view and it helps you with choosing view base on your agent.